# multiple instances of programmable SIP soft phone

Tags: perl, sip, voip

I have recently moved to telecom and working on automation framework to automate the VoIP phone.

In current framework, for a simple call/conference scenario, additional helper phones are being used. The current framework configure these additional physical helper phones which takes considerable time and consumption of resources.

I am trying to replace these physical helper phones with the programmable soft phones, so that the test execution will be little bit fast.

Please let us know if this can be possible.

I am not looking for GUI-based soft SIP client because automating the UI actions will be another challenge and prone to error.

This framework is being developed in Perl

Your help will be highly appreciated!!

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for an automated test tool for SIP, is that right?

Comment: I'd imagine popular softphones like Bria, Zoiper and Blink all have some form of automated provisioning or at the very least the ability to manually update a configuration file.

Comment: yes, they do have something for automated execution. But it seems that only one instance is supported by them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at SIPp. http://sipp.sourceforge.net/

I think it will do what you want, it even has some handling of RTP data.

Answer (score 0):

If perl is not a strict requirement, the [KitCAT](http://echarts.org/KitCAT) framework is extremely (Java) developer-friendly. Test cases are written in JUnit, for ease of integration with other tools. It provides logs at varying levels (including SIP messages), and supports multiple user agents, which can all be coordinated within a test case. (The latter is not well supported in other SIP testing tools, such as sipp). It also provides coordination with other protocols (e.g., RTP, HTTP).

There is a (somewhat dated) [screencast](http://echarts.org/KitCATScreencast/kitcat.htm) that shows installation and basic usage of the tool.

Comment: Thanks yotommy, I will prefer in perl. Let me include the perl keyword if I find something.